# Interpreting 5bit subsets within Packed Binary Data Python

Tags: python, binary

I have been having some real trouble with this for a while. I am receiving a string of binary data in python and I am having trouble unpacking and interpreting only a 5bit subset (not an entire byte) of the data. It seems like whatever method comes to mind just simply fails miserably.

Let's say I have two bytes packed binary data, and I would like to interpret the first 10bits within the 16. How could I convert this to an 2 integers representing 5bits each?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use bitmasks and bitshifting:

```
>>> example = 0x1234   # Hexadecimal example; 2 bytes, 4660 decimal.
>>> bin(example)       # Show as binary digits
'0b1001000110100'
>>> example & 31       # Grab 5 most significant bits
20
>>> bin(example & 31)  # Same, now represented as binary digits
'0b10100'
>>> (example >> 5) & 31 # Grab the next 5 bits (shift right 5 times first)
17
>>> bin(example >> 5 & 31)
'0b10001'
```

The trick here is to know that 31 is a 5-bit bitmask:

```
>>> bin(31)
'0b11111'
>>> 0b11111
31
>>> example & 0b11111
20
```

As you can see you could also just use the `0b` binary number literal notation if you find that easier to work with.

See the [Python Wiki on bit manipulation](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BitManipulation) for more background info.

Comment: Awesome! And Makes perfect sense too.